# The average number in Delphi Console Application

Tags: delphi

I remake my code and its looks like that:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type vector = array[1..100] of integer;
var a:vector;
var i,n:integer;
var br:integer;
var sum,average:real;

begin
  write('Enter number elements of the array: '); readln(n);
    for i:=1 to n do
      begin
        write('Enter ' ,i, ' element: '); readln(a[i]);
      end;
       br:=0;
       sum:=0;
          for i:=1 to n do
          if not(odd(a[i])) and (odd(i)) then
          sum:=sum+a[i];
          br:=br+1;
          average:=sum/br;
          writeln('average= ',average:5:3);
          readln;
end.
```

But when i start my program its finding only the sum , and the counter(br) isnt working and calculate only the sum. Can you help me now about that depending on my code please :) !

Comment: There isn't a single `+` in your program. Calculate the mean by summing the values and dividing by the count. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I tried like this but it have one problem: Incompatible types: Integer and Extended , How to fix it?

Comment: You are wasting our time by asking for help with code that you won't show. I repeat, there is not a single `+` in your code. Please show the code you want help with. I can easily guess but that's not the point. The lesson I want to teach you is how to ask properly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OFFTOPIC: Our time is an our own time and nobody can not waste it except ourselves. A lot of things was done before our born. [http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Arithmetic_mean#Pascal](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Arithmetic_mean#Pascal) for example.

Comment: Is this the continuation from your [previous question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691869/rewriting-from-c-sharp-to-delphi-console-application)?

Comment: If you have more than one line of code that should be executed when a conditional statement is true, you need to enclose the lines in a `begin` - `end` block. And equally for code in a `for` loop

Comment: I give up. I specifically edited the indentation so it would be obvious where you need to insert begin/end. Now you have reverted to your own messed up indentation. Good luck!

Comment: @Abelisto You are right. It's the asker's time that is wasted.

Comment: i make it thank you for all guys :)

Comment: @LuxuS Do you realise that you are using pirated software

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Do you think that this could be the reason that OP's IDE does not have SysUtils?

Comment: @asd-tm he has `SysUtils` but not `System.SysUtils`.

Comment: @David I wonder then why cannot he compile the code. I have instructed him to replace System.SysUtils with SysUtils. And why do you think he has a pirated Delphi? He might be studying in some college with old  software installed... However, I am afraid you are right.

Comment: @asd-tm He's using pirated software, and isn't interested in asking a good question in the spirit of the site. Why waste your efforts?

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to put `begin` and `end`, so `br` is incremented properly:

```
if not(odd(a[i])) and (odd(i)) then
Begin
      sum:=sum+a[i];
      br:=br+1;
End;
average:=sum/br;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the build-in routine [[System.]Math.Mean](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Math.Mean):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.Math;

var
  Count: Integer;
  I: Integer;
  Values: TSingleDynArray;

begin
  try
    Write('Enter number of elements of the array: ');
    ReadLn(Count);
    SetLength(Values, Count);
    for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      Write('Enter element ', I + 1, ': ');
      ReadLn(Values[I]);
    end;
    WriteLn('Average = ', Mean(Values):5:3);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Might be worth adding the modification necessary for D7 - the OP seems to be using the hookey version of it, judging by the error message quoted in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TVector = array of integer;

var
  a: TVector;
  i, n: integer;
  ElSum, Elements: integer;

begin
  write('Enter number of elements: ');
  readln(n);
  SetLength(a, n);
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    write('Enter ', i, ' element: ');
    readln(a[i - 1]);
  end;
  ElSum := 0;
  Elements := 0;
  for i := 1 to n do
    if not(odd(a[i - 1])) and (odd(i)) then
    begin
      inc(ElSum, a[i - 1]);
      inc(Elements);
    end;
  if Elements <> 0 then
    writeln('The average is: ' + floattostr(ElSum / Elements))
  else
    writeln('Can not divide by 0');
  readln;
end.
```

**APPENDED**

In this case the data will be analysed at input. I assume that you will not require the elements of the array in the future. That is why I do not store the values in an array. I also skip `FloatToStr` function.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
//We skip uses System.SysUtils; 
var
  i, n, CurrentInteger,
  ElSum, Elements: integer;

begin
  ElSum := 0;
  Elements := 0;
  write('Enter number of elements: ');
  readln(n);
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    write('Enter ', i, ' element: ');
    readln(CurrentInteger);
    if not(odd(CurrentInteger)) and (odd(i)) then
    begin
      inc(ElSum, CurrentInteger);
      inc(Elements);
    end;
  end;

  if Elements <> 0 then
    begin
      write('The average is: ');
      writeln(ElSum / Elements:5:3)//we write it instead of FloatToStr
    end
  else
    writeln('Can not divide by 0');
  readln;

end.
```

Comment: It shows me error : Undeclared indentifier: floattostr

Comment: @LuXuS In alike cases add the units to uses list. See where the functions are declared: `FloatToStr` is declared in `System.SysUtils` (Delphi XE5)

Comment: [Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(7): File not found: 'System.SysUtils.dcu' (Delphi 7 second edition).

Comment: @LuXuS You can find a function in your help system and add the unit qhere that function is declared. Or type the function name, set cursor to it an press F1. Read the article and add the unit name to uses list.

Comment: @LuXuS It is most likely that in Delphi 7 the unit name was `SysUtils` Use it instead of `System.SysUtils`

Comment: Please write a sentence or two within your answer explaining what you changed to make it work.

Comment: @RobKennedy I have edited the post. Feel free to edit it if you consider it necessary.

Comment: @LuXuS I have edited the post so that you do not need to use SysUtils.